# Why rand() in format function returns null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to generate a 6 digit number in SQL Server, which first digit is allowed to be zero.

For generating a random 6 digit number I use this code:

```
round(rand()*power(10,6),0)
```

For making sure that it is a 6 character number I use as this example:

```
format(12345,'D6')
```

Which returns:

```
012345
```

But when I use below phrase it returns `NULL`

```
select format(round(rand()*power(10,6),0),'D6')
```

I was searching to find the cause, but I just understand that even `format(rand()*power(10,6),'D6')` returns null, while `format(round(power(10,3),0),'D6')` and `select format(power(10,3),'D6')` returns the answer.
It shows that the problem is neither about `power()` nor `round()`. The `rand()` function is the cause.

I use this code to solve my problem:

```
declare @num int = round(rand()*power(10,6),0)

select format(@num,'D6')
```

But I just want to know why `rand()` in `format()` returns null, I couldn't find the cause.

If you have any idea, I'll appreciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: `D` is only a valid style for integers, and `RAND()` produces a `FLOAT`. `format(cast(rand()*power(10,6) as int),'D6')` yields the desired result, but personally I'd prefer something like `select right(power(10, 6) + abs(cast(crypt_gen_random(4) as int)), 6)` (`rand` doesn't vary across rows, and `format` is very slow).

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#standard-format-specifiers) to verify @JeroenMostert statement, which states the format code `d` is *"Supported by: Integral types only."*

Comment: If you also do `declare @num float = round(rand()*power(10,6),0); select format(@num,'D6');` you'll get the same behaviour: `NULL`. As you use an `int` variable, you implicitly convert the `float` to an `int` before you apply `FORMAT`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks! I understand what happened now!

Comment: @Larnu Thanks! I understand what happened now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `rand()*power(10,6)` returns a float.
When you put it into a variable type `int` you force the conversion to int.
We can do the same thing with `cast(.. as int)` as in
`select format(cast(rand()*power(10,6)as int),'D6')` which works correctly. (As the value is already a whole number there is no need to use `round()`)
If we use a variable type float we get a null value:

> ```
> declare @num float = round(rand()*power(10,6),0)    
> select format(@num,'D6')
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | null             |
> ```

The problem therefore occurs when we use `format()` with a float as argument.